# Redirect to another controller/Action not registered in route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

iam having  controller like below which is **not registered in routes table**

```
public class InternalController : Controller
{
 /*this controller is not registered in routes table*/ 

      public ActionResult Foo()
      {
         return Content("Text from foo");
      }
}
```

From another controller which is **registered in Routes table** i want to call/redirect action of previous controller, one which is not registered in routes table.

```
public class AjaxController : Controller
{
 /*this controller is registered in routes table*/  

      public ActionResult Foo()
      {

           /*FROM HERE HOW DO I RETURN CONTENTS OF  
            controller=InternalController, action = Foo
           */

            /*
              i tried below piece of code but that doesnt seem to work
            */

            return RedirectToAction("Foo", "InternalController ");
      } 
}
```

**Defined Routes** (only one item added)

```
    public void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
       routes.MapRoute("Ajax","ajax/{action}",new {
       controller="Ajax",
       action="Index"
       });
   }
```

Comment: What does *`a controller not registered in a route means`*? This doesn't make any sense to me as a sentence.

Comment: If your class is `InternalController`, then you should be redirecting to the "Internal" controller (i.e. not "InternalController") via `RedirectToAction("Foo", "Internal")`.

Comment: @darin  "a controller not registered in a route" : means i have not registered that Controller inside routes table.

Comment: @Rusi Nova, could you show your routes definitions? Hopefully it would make more sense.

Comment: Stupid question, but why isn't it added to routing?

Comment: @thecodeking: its not my actually not decision, reason behind this is we dont want to expose the name of controller we are using internally.

Comment: That's just crazy talk - you don't have to expose the name of the controller in routing. It sounds they just don't want it exposed publicly - in which case use permissions. You can't really use MVC without routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have shown your routes definition, it is obvious that you can never invoke any other controller than `AjaxController`. You simply forbid them in your routes, so `InternalController` could never be served. You will have to change your route definition.

Depending on what you want to achieve and how you want your urls to look like you have a couple of possibilities:

- Leave the default route
- Modify your existing route definition like so:

  ```
  routes.MapRoute(
      "Ajax",
      "{controller}/{action}",
      new { controller = "Ajax", action = "Index" }
  );
  ```

Comment: does this  means its impossible(**even without using redirect**) to return contents of  `controller=InternalController, action = Foo` from  `controller=AjaxControler, action = Foo`.

Comment: @Rusi Nova, yes, that's what it means. And not only it is impossible from `AjaxControler`, but from nowhere, not even by typing some url or whatever in your browser as such url doesn't exist due to the way you have defined your routes. You could still leave the default route (the one generated by the new project wizard).

Comment: yes, all controllers that you want accessible (that includes RedirectToAction calls) need to be registered in the routes

Answer (score 1):

If you are choosing not to register a route... then you probably have the file/controller in a  specific location that will not change.

In that event, just use the "Redirect" method, instead of "RedirectToAction".

For example:

```
return Redirect("~/Internal/Foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create RedirectController for redirecting more Url and pages:

```
public class RedirectController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var rd = this.RouteData.Values;
        string controller = rd["controller2"] as string;
        string action = rd["action2"] as string;

        rd.Remove("controller2");
        rd.Remove("action2");
        rd.Remove("controller");
        rd.Remove("action");

        return RedirectToActionPermanent(action, controller, rd);
    }
}
```

And then you can define redirect from old url in routing tables:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 null, // Name
 "ajax/foo",
 new { controller = "Redirect",
       action = "Index",
       controller2 = "InternalController",
       action2 = "Foo"}
);
```

This pattern is also useful if you redirect old url to new one. For example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
 null, // Name
 "default.aspx", // redirect from old ASP.NET
 new { controller = "Redirect",
 action = "Index",
 controller2 = "Home",
 action2 = "Index" }
);
```